# Delete GRUB From Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I used to have windows 10... then i installed ubuntu 20.04 along with it

Now I want to sell my laptop so I formatted the partition which had ubuntu on it.
But now I have a problem which is when I boot my laptop the grub bootloader keeps showing!

This is what I have tried to do so far

1. I Formatted all the partitions and reset my windows system to factory.
   2)I used cmd as follows:

a)`diskpart`
b)`list disk`
c)`select disk 0`
d)`list volume`
e)`select volume 4` (which is labeled system 570mb)
f)`assign leytter=x`
g)`exit`
h)`x:`
i)`dir`
j)`cd efi`
k)`dir`
l)`rmdir /s ubuntu`

And then i restarted my pc and when i checked again the ubuntu volume was gone bu the grub bootloader still shows when i boot

I booted into bios(uefi) and found that the boot priority is for something called (limpus lite) and when i made the (windows bootloader) at the top the grub menu stoped showing

But how can i get rif of the grub and that limpus lite forever because from time time suddenly when i boot my system it boots to the grub instead windows although the priority is for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the install disk if it has the `efibootmgr` on it then this can delete entries from your `EFI` firmware for any OS you choose to delete. If not installed then try to install it, some of these live disks allow it to happen and get programs not on them.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples